# Matlab: Efficient storage of n 2x2 matrices

Tags: matlab, recursion, storage, iteration

I have a recursive procedure that generates a 2x2 matrix each time the loop iterates. I want to be able to call upon each of these matrices at a later point but I'm not sure how to store them all together efficiently.

If the procedure iterates n times, should I store them in a 2nx2 matrix? But then how would I call upon say the jth matrix (rows 2j-1 and 2j) within this long matrix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html):

```
matrices = cell(n,1);
for ii = 1:n

    % generate your matrix
    matrix_ii = rand(2);

    % store it for later
    matrices{ii} = matrix_ii;

    % [do your stuff]

end
```

Recalling the `j`th matrix is then as simple as

```
matrix_j = matrices{j}
```

(note the curly braces).

You could also store it in a large 2D array (as you suggested),

```
matrices = zeros(2*n,2);
for ii = 1:n

    % generate your 2x2 matrix
    matrix_ii = rand(2);

    % store it for later
    matrices(2*(ii-1)+[0 1]+1,:) = matrix_ii;

    % [do your stuff]

end
```

recalling values later like so:

```
matrix_j = matrices(2*(j-1)+[0 1]+1,:)
```

or in a 3D array like so,

```
matrices = zeros(2,2,n);
for ii = 1:n

    % generate your 2x2 matrix
    matrix_ii = rand(2);

    % store it for later
    matrices(:,:,ii) = matrix_ii;

    % [do your stuff]

end
```

recalling values later like so:

```
matrix_j = matrices(:,:,j);
```

Comparing the methods for `n = 1e5`:

```
Elapsed time is 0.282959 seconds.  % cell arrays
Elapsed time is 0.856801 seconds.  % 2*n x 2 matrix
Elapsed time is 0.293186 seconds.  % 2x2xn array

Memory: 9200000 bytes  % Cell arrays 
Memory: 3200000 bytes  % 2*n x 2 matrix 
Memory: 3200000 bytes  % 2x2xn array
```

You might want to test these things on your own computer, but it appears the large 3D array is the best way to go here.

Comment: Note, however, that the memory consumption of this cell approach is about 4 times higher compared to storing the `n` `2 x 2` matrices in a `2 x 2 x n` 3D matrix. On the other hand, the cell approach seems to be much faster than storing the 2D matrices in the `2 x 2 x n` matrix.

Comment: @H.Muster: Indeed. this has always struck me as odd; cells "should" be no more than a container for pointers to data, right? But that's not -quite- what is going on...Anyway, I'll edit it in for completeness.

Comment: Nice answer (+1). I am a bit confused that the elapsed time for the cell code and the 2x2xn array code does not differ for you. On my system the latter is much slower.

Comment: @H.Muster: I know, I have an APU which has so far *always* given me results incompatible with most people here...In this case I'm not complaining, but it's not very reproducible. Perhaps you can edit in your results (and change the conclusion accordingly)?

Comment: +1 I posted a slightly modified benchmark, with an improved code for the second method.

Answer (score 1):

[Rody Oldenhuis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16792605/97160) gave three great alternatives to store the matrices in his answer (which I already upvoted). I just wanted to improve upon the slowest of the three.

MATLAB matrices are indexed faster by columns rather than by rows, so I'm building a big wide matrix (2-by-2*n) rather than a tall matrix (2*n-by-2). Also building the index in the iterations can be simplified.

Here is the result of that, with a slightly more convenient benchmark (you will need the [TIMEIT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798-timeit-benchmarking-function) function from the File Exchange)

```
function [t,b] = test_2d_matrices_container()
    N = 1e5;
    f = {@()func_cell(N), @()func_wide_2d_mat(N), @()func_3d_mat(N)};

    t = cellfun(@timeit, f);
    b = cellfun(@get_mem, f);
end

function b = get_mem(f)
    x = feval(f);    %#ok<NASGU>
    S = whos('x');
    b = S.bytes;
end

function M = func_cell(N)
    M = cell(N,1);
    for i=1:N
        M{i} = rand(2);
    end
end

function M = func_wide_2d_mat(N)
    M = zeros(2,2*N);
    for i=1:2:2*N
        M(:,[i i+1]) = rand(2);
    end
end

function M = func_3d_mat(N)
    M = zeros(2,2,N);
    for i=1:N
        M(:,:,i) = rand(2);
    end
end
```

The results I get on my machine:

```
>> [t,b] = test_2d_matrices_container
t =
      0.13963      0.22997      0.23434
b =
     9200000     3200000     3200000
```

Now the "wide" 2D matrix case is as fast as the 3D "slices" method (even lightly faster, but the difference is really negligible)